# Regex - Optional Capturing group ignored and captured by previous group

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-lookarounds

I have a list of activities which contain 3 pieces of information which I am trying to extract however the 3rd field is optional, is has the format of `Activity ID - Activity Name - Parent Activity ID` so some examples are:

```
1 - Activity 1
2 - Activity 2
3 - Activity 3 - child of Activity 1 - 1
4 - Activity 4 - 2
5 - Activity 5 - 1
```

My initial Regex was `([0-9]*) - ([a-zA-Z0-9 \-]*) - ([0-9]*)` however this completely ignored the first 2 examples and gave me:

```
3 - Activity 3 - child of Activity 1 - 1
Group 1:3
Group 2:Activity 3 - child of Activity 1
Group 3:1
4 - Activity 4 - 2
Group 1:4
Group 2:Activity 4
Group 3:2
5 - Activity 5 - 1
Group 1:5
Group 2:Activity 5
Group 3:1
```

I then changed this to `([0-9]*) - ([a-zA-Z0-9 \-]*)(?: - ([0-9]*))?` to make the final capturing group optional and enclose it in a non capturing group with the `-`. This now matches all of the examples however it includes `Parent Activity ID` in with `Activity Name` rather than as a separate group. This returned:

```
1 - Activity 1
Group 1:1
Group 2:Activity 1
2 - Activity 2
Group 1:2
Group 2:Activity 2
3 - Activity 3 - child of Activity 1 - 1
Group 1:3
Group 2:Activity 3 - child of Activity 1 - 1
4 - Activity 4 - 2
Group 1:4
Group 2:Activity 4 - 2
5 - Activity 5 - 1
Group 1:5
Group 2:Activity 5 - 1
```

How can I change my RegEx so that the final group is optional and when it's not there it will either return nothing for that group or an empty string and when it is present not include it in the `Activity Name` when it is present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^([0-9]*) - ([a-zA-Z0-9 \-]*?)(?: - ([0-9]*))?$
```

It uses non-greedy (aka lazy) modifier `*?` for your second group, so it leaves last part for next groups to match if possible.

Example of matching [here](https://regex101.com/r/ereG4Q/1).

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, I'd not come across the lazy modifier before, I'll be sure to remember that one.